# после помещения в массив, чернобелое изображение стает зеленоватых цветов

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pil, pillow

```
from PIL import Image
from pylab import *

im = array(Image.open('empire.jpg').convert('L'))


imshow(im)

show()
```

Если в массив не помещать то оно черно белое, благодаря convert('L').Читаю книгу там про это нечего не указано, предполагается что оно и остается черно белым.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже проблема возникает в момент вывода изображения на экран при помощи `pylab` / `matplotlib`.

Попробуйте сохранить массив в файл как изображение и открыть его любым "просматривальщиком" - вы увидите черно-белую картинку:

```
im = Image.open('empire.jpg').convert('L')
Image.fromarray(pylab.array(im)).save("d:/temp/a.jpg")
```

Comment: Видимо так и буду каждый раз конвертить в image потом уже картинку смотреть

Answer (score 1):

Вы не установили палитру для вывода изображения в оттенках серого. Для этого у imshow есть параметр cmap.

Пример:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = np.random.random_sample((10, 10))

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(im)
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(im, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Этот способ не совесем подходит к сожалению